# Переместить видео на право от текста

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="osn">
<div class="text_osn">
    <h1>our strong<br> organaisation</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis cing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ut labore et. ectetur adig ipis cing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
</div>
<div class="btn"><a href=""><span>Contact Us</span></a></div>

<div class="vid"><video src="pomehi.mp4" controls width="360" height="240"><source type="video/mp4"></video></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
    background-color: #313030;
}

.header ul {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.header ul li {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.header ul li a {
    color: #e0e0e0;
}

.header ul li:hover {
    background-color: #ff3f40;
    transition: .4s;
}

.text_osn {
    max-width: 500px;
}

.text_osn p {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.text_osn h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.btn span {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff3f40;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.btn {
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Нужно примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  background-color: #313030;
}

.header ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.header ul li {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header ul li a {
  color: #e0e0e0;
}

.header ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ff3f40;
  transition: .4s;
}

.osn {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.text_osn {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.text_osn p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.text_osn h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.btn span {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff3f40;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.btn {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.vid {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/index.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="osn">
    <div class="text_osn">
      <h1>our strong<br> organaisation</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis cing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. ectetur adig ipis cing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn"><a href=""><span>Contact Us</span></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vid"><video src="pomehi.mp4" controls width="360" height="240"><source type="video/mp4"></video></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! :) Кстати. Там где вы добавили float: left; и по идеи этого достаточно, разве нет? И overflow и position не нужны вроде)

Answer (score 0):

Обернуть текст и видео в контейнер и задать

```
display: flex;
```

Вот пример

```css
   .wrapper{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }
        .element{
            width: 49%;
            background-color: #736357;
            height: 300px;
        }
        h2{
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="element">
           <h2> Тут текст </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="element">
            <h2>Тут картинка</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```